# How to design below card in Flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

I need to design a card having an address whose size is unknown(as shown in bottom middle). The card need to grow according to the size of that address. The alignments should as shown in the image.
I tried Wrap, Flexible, ListView and some other ways but none of them worked.

Comment: added more details to my answer regarding column!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the width in a container, and the height will be automatically adjusted based on the child size.

```
Center(
  child: Card(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        child: Text('your text here...'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image: example]

You can add more widgets by using columns and rows, make sure that the `mainAxisSize` of your column is `MainAxisSize.min`. This will ensure that the column will try to minimize the height it takes..

```
Card(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: Container(
      width: 100,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Industry',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Text('your text here...'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image: result]

Comment: With some more modifications, your answer worked for me